# Select multiple id's php/mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to select multiple id's from my database example:

```
<input id=1 type="text" name="iDEAL" value=0 size=3>
<input id=2 type="text" name="PayPal" value=0 size=3>
```

I need to get the id from the database and still have the value from the input so now i have

```
$ideal = $_POST['iDEAL'];
$paypal = $_POST['PayPal'];
```

I was thinking i need some mysql query like the following:

```
$query = "SELECT bet_id FROM betalingsmethode WHERE  bet_id = ". $_POST['id'] . ""
```

From this point on I am stuck I can't think of a way to make this happen 10 times including formulas. I thought of a switch but then realised it stops after the first hit so that won't be an option.

I hope you guys have a solution.

E//

my database has the following structure

```
Betaalmethodes
 bet_id
 bet_naam

bundels
 bundels_id
 psp_id
 etc

tarieven
 id
 bet_id
 etc
```

I need to know the bet_id so i can tell php which bundle it needs to use for the formula same goes for 'tarieven' where i'll need the correct bundel_id.

Comment: Add your DB structure aswell, and your result and expected result

Comment: to prevent injection note that dont use `$_POST['id']` directly in your query !

Comment: Couldn't get a clear view from your question...Please elaborate bit more.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT bet_id FROM betalingsmethode WHERE  bet_id in (list of all the ids)
```

IN is basically used as OR boolean operation,
for example if you want to get rows having ids 1, 2 and 3. you can get them like

```
SELECT * from table_name where id in (1,2,3)
```

This will bring the rows having the id value as 1 or 2 or 3

Don't write inline queries even though you are using integer but still they are in secure.

Use mysql escape string function (google it) to clean them to avoid sql injection.